# Setting FlushMode.COMMIT in Spring

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I would like set my Hibernate/JPA FlushMode to COMMIT, but in configuration file (applicationContenxt.xml is one of my files), i have a entityManager in my DAO, but i don't know how to set this in configuration file.

So, this is my applicationContext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd">

    <!-- Seta anotaçoes para serem usadas pelo Spring -->
    <context:annotation-config />

    <!-- Define o pacote onde o Spring vai procurar por beans anotados -->
    <context:component-scan
        base-package="br.com.sender" />

    <!-- define que as transaçoes irao ser anotadas -->
    <tx:annotation-driven proxy-target-class="true" /> 

    <!-- Configuracao do Banco de Dados -->
    <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost/sender" />
        <property name="username" value="postgres" />
        <property name="password" value="pgadmin" />
    </bean>

    <!-- Configuracao do Hibernate -->
    <bean id="entityManagerFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="senderPU" />
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
                <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect" />
                <property name="showSql" value="true" />
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <!-- Configuracao do gerente de transacoes do Spring -->
    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

EDIT 1:

I tried the following in applicationContext.xml

```
<bean id="entityManagerFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
          <property name="jpaDialect">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect">
            <property name="flushMode" value="COMMIT"/>
        </bean>
        </property>
```

Tomcat error:

```
aused by: org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'flushMode' of bean class [org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect]: Bean property 'flushMode' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.setPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:1052)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.setPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:921)
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:76)
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:58)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1358)
    ... 53 more
```

**SOLUTION:**

After a lot of research, i found a solution. I setted the FlushMode in @PersistenceContext in my BasicDAO class. Look:

```
@PersistenceContext(type = javax.persistence.PersistenceContextType.EXTENDED, 
        properties = @PersistenceProperty(name="org.hibernate.flushMode", value="COMMIT"))
    protected EntityManager entityManager;
```

This works fine. I removed all @Transactional annotation from my "find" functions, because with @Transactional the "COMMIT" are fired and flush too.

Comment: Hope this helps . http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13259677/how-do-i-set-flush-mode-to-commit-in-my-configuration-files

Comment: i've edited my post with more informations, @ArunM.